# Getting random request timeouts with one application when on office network, but not when using other web applications or on another network

Tags: java, spring, apache, networking

I'm working on a java(13)/spring boot(2.3)/thymeleaf application, fronted by apache(2.4), hosted on Google Cloud Platform, and users working out of the office are experiencing random request timeouts with it. The users in the office are also working in several 3rd party web applications throughout the day, but only have the timeout issue with ours. The timeouts are NOT specific to a feature, time of day, or individual user, and they happen often enough to be a pretty big productivity killer. Some days are better than others, but it's rare that a day will go by without someone running into it. When the issue does happen, the users can usually just refresh their browser and the next request works. However, sometimes they can't gets any requests (GET, POST, PUT, etc..) to go through for several minutes at a time.

The error message looks something like: This site can't be reached. It took too long to respond. ERR_TIMED_OUT

Here's the kicker - it only happens to users working on the office network. We have a lot of people working from home now, and they NEVER (literally) experience this issue. The people in the office have started turning their phones into mobile hotspots and working around the issue that way.

Before you dismiss this as JUST an office network issue, don't forget that this only happens with our application. We also have a very basic office network setup and don't host any internal servers. We just have a cable modem/router, some switches, and WiFi. We've replaced all of the hardware now thinking something had gone bad, and we enlisted the support of external network specialists who couldn't find anything wrong with the network setup or internet connection. We've even tried changing internet service providers, maximizing bandwidth (we get about 150mbp/sec down right now), and nothing has worked.

My question with all of this is, what am I missing or how can I diagnose this? If it's a network issue, why does it only happen with 1 web application when many are used? If it's an application issue, what could make it a problem on just one network and nowhere else?

Comment: Really hard to figure out...  Bypass DNS resolution by putting the IP in the local hosts files.  Reproduce using Fiddler on a client workstation and see if it affects a specific request (ex. always the same page, or same resource).  Do you have access filtering?  We had something like this with PaloAlto external access filters.  What about caches (ex. corporate proxy).  Do you know all (and control all) network components until you reach the provider?  Can you test with the same provider from outside your company network?  This will validate if it is you or the provider issue.

Comment: Thanks Nic3500. I'll try bypassing the dns on one of the machines. We've tried everything to find a way to consistently reproduce it and have come up empty. We had users send us the problem url every time for a while, but found no pattern. We don't have any access filtering, and "yes" I can control all network components until the provider (there's only a few). We have tested with the same provider from outside the company network and don't have any issues. Is it possible that something in our network is adding something to the requests that would trip-up apache?

Comment: Only a sniffer as the last exit point to the provider could validate what is exiting the company network.  You could then compare that to the actual request made by the user.  I do not envy you this type of troubleshooting, it can get quite confusing!  Note that is not unheard of to have issues with cloud providers, I have heard such stories where I work (something to do with BGP routing vs provider and cloud).  Crazy to figure out though!